# SqlException: El nombre de columna 'nombre_columna' no es válido ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Tengo un error al realizar una consulta con LINQ y al ejecutarse da el error `SqlException: El nombre de columna 'Monedas_nombre' no es válido`. Cualquier aporte es bienvenido y desde ya muchas gracias!
La clase Insumo (que es la que genera el error al consultarse desde la DB):

```
namespace AccesoDatos.Contexto.Produccion
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class Insumos
    {
        public Insumos()
        {
            DetallesMovimientosBandejas = new HashSet<DetallesMovimientosBandejas>();
            Detalle_Ajuste_Insumos = new HashSet<Detalle_Ajuste_Insumos>();
            Detalle_Compra = new HashSet<Detalle_Compra>();
            Detalle_Envasado = new HashSet<Detalle_Envasado>();
            Detalle_Formula = new HashSet<Detalle_Formula>();
            Detalle_Formula_Envasado = new HashSet<Detalle_Formula_Envasado>();
            Detalle_Orden_Compra = new HashSet<Detalle_Orden_Compra>();
            Envasado = new HashSet<Envasado>();
            Insumos_Formulas_Recuperado = new HashSet<Insumos_Formulas_Recuperado>();
            Mov_Ins_Asoc = new HashSet<Mov_Ins_Asoc>();
            Productos = new HashSet<Productos>();
            Productos1 = new HashSet<Productos>();
            Formulas = new HashSet<Formulas>();
            Productos2 = new HashSet<Productos>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Codigo_Interno_Insumos { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [StringLength(13)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido")]
        public string Codigo_Insumo { get; set; }

        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Codigo_Insumo_Proveedor { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Descripcion_Larga { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido")]
        public int Codigo_Linea { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido")]
        public int Codigo_Rubro { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Comentario { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido")]
        public int Codigo_Proveedor { get; set; }

        public int? Codigo_Proveedor_Alternativo { get; set; }

        public int? Codigo_Ultimo_Proveedor { get; set; }

        public int? Codigo_Iva { get; set; }

        public int? Codigo_Impuesto_Interno { get; set; }

        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Codigo_Imputacion { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public string Unidad_Medida { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? Fecha_Ultima_Compra { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.####}")]
        public decimal? Precio_Ultima_Compra { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.####}")]
        public decimal? Precio_Lista { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.####}")]
        public decimal? Punto_Pedido { get; set; }

        public bool? Activo { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public string Precio_Por { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Moneda { get; set; }

        public bool Materia_Prima { get; set; }

        public bool Leche { get; set; }

        public bool Masa { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Detalle_Ajuste_Insumos> Detalle_Ajuste_Insumos { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Detalle_Compra> Detalle_Compra { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Detalle_Envasado> Detalle_Envasado { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Detalle_Formula> Detalle_Formula { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Detalle_Formula_Envasado> Detalle_Formula_Envasado { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Detalle_Orden_Compra> Detalle_Orden_Compra { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Envasado> Envasado { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Insumos_Formulas_Recuperado> Insumos_Formulas_Recuperado { get; set; }

        public virtual Monedas Monedas { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Mov_Ins_Asoc> Mov_Ins_Asoc { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Productos> Productos { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Productos> Productos1 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Formulas> Formulas { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Productos> Productos2 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DetallesMovimientosBandejas> DetallesMovimientosBandejas { get; set; }

    }

}
```

La clase Monedas (que es la que intuyo que es el problema):

```
namespace AccesoDatos.Contexto.Produccion
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Monedas
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Monedas()
        {
            //Insumos = new HashSet<Insumos>();
        }

        [Key]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string nombre { get; set; }

        public double intercambio { get; set; }

        public bool nacional { get; set; }

        //[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        //public virtual ICollection<Insumos> Insumos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

La parte de mi controller que hace la consulta a la DB:

```
var formula = this.FormulasServicio.Obtener((f) => f.Codigo_Producto == producto).FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var item in formula.Detalle_Formula.Where((df) => df.Marca)){
    var insumo = this.InsumosServicio.Obtener((i) => i.Codigo_Insumo == item.Codigo_Insumo).SingleOrDefault();
...
}
```

Cabe aclarar que esto que está comentado sobre Insumos en Monedas es porque generaba una referencia circular entre clases y daba error en una parte del sistema, pero al comentarlo genera esta otro error.

Edición:
Agrego el schema de la tabla Monedas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: verifica que no estés enviando un valor nulo

Comment: Hola @Shassain nono, no se está enviando ningún valor nulo

Comment: Podrias agregar el schema de tu tabla?

Comment: Hola @JulioGuerrero ahí agregué el schema!